# How to use EventEmitter in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

Whenever I create EventEmitter it is throwing an error as

> Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.

```
statusUpdated = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

tried this:

```
statusUpdated = new EventEmitter<>;
statusUpdated = new EventEmitter<>();
statusUpdated = new EventEmitter<{}>();
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: from where do you import the EventEmmitter ?

Comment: it got imported from import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must import it from core

```
import {EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'
```

Comment: that's what I just wanted to say :)

Answer (score 1):

The proper definition would be:

```
statusUpdated:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
```